# Java random number generated game using java

Tags: java

I am creating the simple game using random number generated. if the number is enter on the text field is correct and match with the ramdom number game is win other wise try again. but if the number is matched with ramdom   always display the message Try again. What I try so far I wrote below.

```
  Random r = new Random();
        int low = 1;
        int high = 10;
        
        int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
        lbltxt.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        String text = lbltxt.getText();

        if(txtRam.equals(text))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Will");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Try Again");
        }
```

what is text printed on the lbltxt.getText()   i equal in to txtRam txtfiled but no is equal fine but display as Try again

Comment: Whats `txtRam` supposed to be? That variable is nowhere declared in the code above.

Comment: txrRam mean textfield name

Comment: what is text printed on the lbltxt.getText()   i equal in to txtRam txtfiled but no is equal fine but display as Try again

Comment: Double check what's the value of txtRam and text. Print them out and you'll see what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to **debug** and **check** what's the value you're getting from both `txtRam` and `text` variables. You could also convert the generated random number to a String to compare it with the txtRam.

```java
// Generate random number
Random r = new Random();
int low = 1;
int high = 10;
int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
if( txtRam.equals(Integer.toString(result)) ) {
   // Equal
} else {
   // Not equal
}
```